# Three.js: polyhedron rounded corners (faces)

Tags: javascript, three.js, polyhedra

I've created a polyhedron and it has rounded corners (or even faces - I don't know which explanation is correct). How can I set border-radius?

Is it possible to remove rounding and make usual corners?

Code is below.

```html
    <html> 
<head

    > 
        <title>Моё 3</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div id="ThreeJS" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>
        <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/Three.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/Stats.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>
    <script>
    /*
        Three.js "tutorials by example"
        Author: Lee Stemkoski
        Date: July 2013 (three.js v59dev)
    */
    
    // MAIN
    var polyhedronShape, polyhedronPts = [], cube, mesh;
    // standard global variables
    var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
    var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
    var clock = new THREE.Clock();
    
    // custom global variables
    var targetList = [];
    var projector, mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    
    init();
    animate();
    
    // FUNCTIONS        
    function init() 
    {
        // SCENE
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        // CAMERA
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
        var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        scene.add(camera);
        camera.position.set(0,150,400);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
        // RENDERER
        if ( Detector.webgl )
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
        else
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        // EVENTS
        THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
        THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });
        // CONTROLS
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        // STATS
        stats = new Stats();
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
        stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
        container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
        // LIGHT
        var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
        light.position.set(0,250,0);
        scene.add(light);
        // FLOOR
        var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/checkerboard.jpg' );
        floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
        floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
        var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
        var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
        var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
        floor.position.y = -0.5;
        floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        scene.add(floor);
        // SKYBOX/FOG
        var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
        var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9999ff, side: THREE.BackSide } );
        var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
        scene.add(skyBox);
        
        ////////////
        // CUSTOM //
        ////////////
    
        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
        // this material causes a mesh to use colors assigned to faces
        var faceColorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
        { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );
        
        var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 80, 32, 16 );
        for ( var i = 0; i < sphereGeometry.faces.length; i++ ) 
        {
            face = sphereGeometry.faces[ i ];   
            face.color.setRGB( 0, 0, 0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2 );       
        }
        var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, faceColorMaterial );
        sphere.position.set(0, 50, 0);
        scene.add(sphere);
        
        targetList.push(sphere);
    
    
        
        // Create an array of materials to be used in a cube, one for each side
        var cubeMaterialArray = [];
        // order to add materials: x+,x-,y+,y-,z+,z-
        cubeMaterialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff3333 } ) );
        cubeMaterialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff8800 } ) );
        cubeMaterialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff33 } ) );
        cubeMaterialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x33ff33 } ) );
        cubeMaterialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x3333ff } ) );
        cubeMaterialArray.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x8833ff } ) );
        var cubeMaterials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( cubeMaterialArray );
        // Cube parameters: width (x), height (y), depth (z), 
        //        (optional) segments along x, segments along y, segments along z
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1 );
        // using THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() in the constructor below
        //   causes the mesh to use the materials stored in the geometry
        cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterials );
        cube.position.set(-100, 50, -50);
        scene.add( cube );      
        targetList.push(cube);
    
        
        
        // polyhedron
    
        polyhedronPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( -100, 600 ) );
        polyhedronPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 300, 600 ) );
        polyhedronPts.push( new THREE.Vector2 ( 600, -100 ) );
        
        polyhedronShape = new THREE.Shape( polyhedronPts );
    
        var extrudeSettings = {amount: 20}; // bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2 , bevelSegments: 5, bevelSize: 8, bevelThickness:5
        
        var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( polyhedronShape, extrudeSettings );
    
        mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00cc00 } ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff3333, wireframe: true, transparent: true } ) ] );
        mesh.position.set( -50, 50, 300 );
        mesh.rotation.set( 300, 0, 0 );
        //mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
        scene.add( mesh );
        targetList.push(mesh);
    
    
        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        // initialize object to perform world/screen calculations
        projector = new THREE.Projector();
        
        // when the mouse moves, call the given function
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
        
    }
    
    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
    {
        // the following line would stop any other event handler from firing
        // (such as the mouse's TrackballControls)
        // event.preventDefault();
        
        //console.log("Click.");
        
        // update the mouse variable
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
        
        // find intersections
    
        // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
        //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
        var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );
    
        // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
        var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList );
        
        // if there is one (or more) intersections
        if ( intersects.length > 0 )
        {
            console.log("Hit @ " + toString( intersects[0].point ) );
            // change the color of the closest face.
            intersects[ 0 ].face.color.setRGB( 0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2, 0, 0 ); 
            intersects[ 0 ].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
        }
    
    }
    
    function toString(v) { return "[ " + v.x + ", " + v.y + ", " + v.z + " ]"; }
    
    function animate() 
    {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        render();       
        update();
    }
    
    function update()
    {
        if ( keyboard.pressed("z") ) 
        { 
            // do something
        }
        
        controls.update();
        stats.update();
    }
    
    function render() 
    {
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean smooth faces?

[image]

The way to make your edges 'hard' is to first add this to your material options:

```
shading: THREE.FlatShading,
```

And then possibly:

```
geometry.computeVertexNormals()
```

Comment: I've added shading to one and to both of materials in this line:
`polyhedron = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00cc00, shading: THREE.FlatShading } ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff3333, shading: THREE.FlatShading, wireframe: true, transparent: true } ) ] );`
and got no result.
Also I've added a line `geometry.computeVertexNormals();` before and after previous one and also got no result. Any other ideas?

Comment: That what I call rounded corners (or faces) - [screenshot](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/727/4276846630.png).